# Maximum difference between columns using relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

Is it possible to obtain the maximum difference between two columns (for example starting and ending weights)?

Right now I'm leaning towards no as this would require a new column with the difference between the two columns for each row, then taking the max of that. Doing it the way I orginally intended doesn't work either since arithmetic operations are not allowed in the conditions of select operations (e.g. SIGMA (c1 - c2 < c3 - c4)(Table) is not allowed).

Disclosure: this is part of a homework question.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, the result of "the maximum difference between two columns" is a scalar value, whereas result of any relational operation is a relation.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, exactly in the way you planned, but you need generalized projection for that. The generalized projection is the operator

```
Π(E1, E2,..., En)R
```

where R is a relation, and E1...En are expressions in the form a⊕b, where a and b are attributes of R or constants, and ⊕ is an arbitrary binary operator between them. The result is a relation with attributes E1...En.

This would allow you to project the differences into a new relation (R' := Π(x-y)R), then find the maximum on that, just as you planned.

If we're not allowed to use generalized projection, then I think we have no means to actually subtract an attribute from another, or to actually calculate anything from them, as the definition of projection allow only attribute names, and the definition of selection allow only expressions of the form aθb where a and b are attributes or constants and θ is a binary relational operator (this is logical, in its way, because if we have a relation R(X,Y), then we have no idea about the *type* of X or Y, making operations on them quite meaningless).

I think generalized projection is a great extension to relational algebra. It's obviously immensely useful in real life, and it can be defended even from a more scientific point of view: if we allow binary conditional operators on the values like "X > 50", then we made assumptions on the type already, rendering that point kind of moot. Your instructor may disagree, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this in the real world, you should be able to do this with a subquery (or a view, which amounts to much the same thing), something like:

```
select max (diff) from (
    select high - low as diff from blah blah blah
)
```

Whether this applies to the abstract world of relational algebra, I couldn't say. I'm too busy fixing those damn real-world problems :-)